# Android Volley Json Post request not working

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I would like to send a JsonObjectRequest request to php. POST accepting null in  index.php.
how can i send them from my android client? this is the code.

AppController.java

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

index.php

```
 <?php
  if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
        $tag = $_POST['tag'];
        require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
        $db = new DB_Functions();
                $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
                if ($user) {
                    $response["error"] = FALSE;
                    $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                    $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                    $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                    $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                    $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                    echo json_encode($response);
                } else {
                    $response["error"] = TRUE;
                    $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
    } else {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 'tag' is missing!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

Registration.jaca

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnRegister;
    private Button btnLinkToLogin;
    private EditText inputFullName;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    registerUser(name, email, password);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
     * email, password) to register url
     * */
    private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
            final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                        hideDialog();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                            if (!error) {
                                // User successfully stored in MySQL
                                // Now store the user in sqlite
                                String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                                JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                                String name = user.getString("name");
                                String email = user.getString("email");
                                String created_at = user
                                        .getString("created_at");

                                // Inserting row in users table
                                db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                                // Launch login activity
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        RegisterActivity.this,
                                        LoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else {

                                // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                                // message
                                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        hideDialog();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "register");
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

error is "Required parameter 'tag' is missing! getting this error on android device.
What should I do to solve this issue.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you read [Google's training documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) yet?

Comment: you got the error on the device, but it came from the php naturally, can you share the code that actually sends the request? also look at these:  [SO regarding Volley and POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725843/empty-response-received-on-android-post-request/30726820#30726820) , and this [SO regarding Volley and POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496511/volley-and-gson-sending-a-post-request-using-jsonobjectrequest/30548139#30548139)

Comment: needles to say, all of the above would make sense assuming you went through the link @BNK mentioned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481228/post-method-using-volley-not-working